# How to build a HTML object in python3?

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-2.x

It used to be easy to build an HTML instance. In python 2:

```
import html
obj = html.HTML('html')
```

But in python3, there is no attribute as "HTML" under "html" module.
And I am working on an specific environment and not allowed to install packages there. I wonder if there is anyway to build an HTML object in python3 so that I can use "obj.head","obj.div","obj.p" and other functions.
Thanks.

Comment: What package provides `html` ? It's not a built in package in python 2.7 or 3.x.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an `"html object"` via an external python libray. [Domonic](https://github.com/byteface/domonic)

> Create HTML with python 3 using a standard DOM API. Includes a python port of JavaScript for interoperability and tons of other cool features. A fast prototyping library.

In example you can do something like this:

```py
from domonic.html import *
from domonic import domonic

x = html(body(h1('Hello, World!')))
mydom = domonic.parseString(x)

# Do something with parsed dom here.
```

Documentation Here: [Domonic Docs](https://domonic.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Request states can't install anything.

Comment: @Brian What do you exactly mean?

Comment: in the question text: "And I am working on an specific environment and not allowed to install packages there."